# Shielding that retains some attenuation as \$\omega \rightarrow 0\$?

Tags: electromagnetism, shielding

I'm new to the world of shielding.

It seems that with regular, "Faraday type", shielding you're at the mercy of the skin effect equation:

[image]

Which blows up as \$\omega \rightarrow 0\$

Are there any active or more exotic shielding designs that retain some attenuation as  \$\omega \rightarrow 0\$?

Comment: Specifically, are you shielding against E or H fields at low frequencies and, specifically what are you trying to shield and how vulnerable is it?

Comment: E fields primarily; I'm trying to shield humans.

Comment: E and H also decouple as \$\omega \rightarrow 0\$. So there's no meaning of EM waves down there, and just E or H will do (y'know, or both, if applicable :) ).

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, are you shielding against E or H fields?

> *E fields primarily*

The skin effect problem is only a problem with low frequency magnetic fields i.e. magnetic fields penetrate and pass-through much more easily at lower frequencies. Regarding E fields, they are killed off pretty easily with a conductive shield especially if grounded; think a two plate capacitor and inserting a third plate in-between <-- it kills-off the coupling.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense...so is there some type of shielding that retains some magnetic coupling (I guess you'd call it) as w-> 0?

Comment: Do you mean a material that is magnetic?